# iOS custom font in resources subdirectory

Tags: ios, fonts, xamarin

I'm trying to place my custom fonts into Resources/Fonts/MyFontFamily subdirectory, however I'm having problems on how to load them from the code.
In my info.plist I've added:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>/Fonts/MyFontFamily/MyFont-Regular.ttf</string>
```

In the code I do

```
var font = UIFont.FromName(@"/Fonts/MyFontFamily/MyFont-Regular.ttf", 14);
```

However the font is null, If I place the font directly in the Resources folder and change info.plist and font path in the method UIFont.FromName accordingly it does load the font. Is it not possible to have custom fonts placed in Resources subdirectory?

**Edit**: I've tried both with and without "/" at the start of the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### info.plist

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Fonts/MyFontFamily/MyFont-Regular.ttf</string>
```

Note: Do not include "/" at the beginning of the array string.

Note: This assumes that your fonts are in the `Fonts/MyFontFamily` subdirectory of your `Resources`.

#### Flag your fonts to *Always Copy*:

[image]

#### Code:

```
var font = UIFont.FromName(@"MyFont-Regular", 20);
```

#### Note: This is the font name as seen in the **Font Book**

i.e.:

```
PinyonScript-Regular.ttf
```

Is opened via:

```
var font = UIFont.FromName(@"Pinyon Script", 20);
```

*Quick font name check*, open the font in `Font Book` and look at the name of the font in the title bar:

[image]

Comment: Didnt see that '/' good catch, think I need more coffee or beer now that its friday!

Comment: I've already tried with and without "/" at the beginning before. The actual problem was I was trying to load the font not with its font book name but with its file name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dont think you need the "Fonts" bit at the start of the path try :

```
var font = UIFont.FromName(@"MyFont-Regular.ttf", 14);
```

OR

```
var font = UIFont.FromName(@"MyFontFamily/MyFont-Regular.ttf", 14);
```

Comment: I've already tried this and several other combinations, none of which seems to work.

Comment: Are your fonts set to `Build Action` > `BundleResource` ? if you right click on them.

Comment: Yes, I made sure of that.

Comment: Cool no worries, got to watch out when re-naming fonts ;)