# Apply custom font on label in xamarin.iOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to apply Montserrat-Light font style in all the label and entry, I am doing it by making a renderer of controls. EntryRenderer is working fine but LabelRenderer is giving ArgumentNullException with message: Value can not be null.

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(ExtendedLabelRenderer))]
namespace NewApp.iOS.Renderer
{
public class ExtendedLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {

            Control.Font = UIFont.FromName("Montserrat-Light", 10f);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No it's not ,because i applied Background Color and it works fine

Comment: Then what is null? have you debugged it?

Comment: yes but it always shows exception in  Control.Font = UIFont.FromName("Montserrat-Light", 10f);  this line

Comment: If the font can't be found then the `UIFont.FromName("Montserrat-Light", 10f);` line will produce null or check if Control != null instead of NewElement. Also, why are you using a custom renderer? This can be done perfectly with styles :)

Comment: If your font is returning null then review: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36942128/4984832

Comment: @GeraldVersluis FYI: Since he is applying that font to all labels/entries, custom renderers are faster & more efficient than using a style.

Comment: Please tell me any other way of doing this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36942128/4984832 this is already followed by me

Comment: What should be the build action of a .ttf file

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It will update if you haven't specified font-family and size in your XAML. Now you can set in your XAML also.

```
 public class CustomLabelRender : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.FontFamily))
                    Control.Font = UIFont.FromName(this.Element.FontFamily, (nfloat)e.NewElement.FontSize);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: still it is giving same exception

Comment: Can you please share Xaml code?. Also you have to add fonts in info.plist file. Have you added?

Comment: yes i have added it in info.plist , i am not doing something special in my xaml, just adding a custom renderer

Comment: <key>UIAppFonts</key>
 <string>Montserrat-Light.ttf</string>    added in info.plist

Comment: Please add this key "<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>" in info.plist file once and check.

Answer (score 0):

As an easier approach to this issue, I would like to recommend the `Label` element and/or the `CustomFontEffect` of the free, open source Forms9Patch NuGet package.  It allows you to store your custom font as an Embedded Resource in your Xamarin.Forms application's cross platform project (.NetStandard, PCL, or Shared Library) and then set that font's Embedded Resource ID as the `FontFamily` for any Xamarin.Forms element that has the `FontFamily` property.

```
var entry = new Xamarin.Forms.Entry {
    Text = "Xamarin.Forms.Entry element",
    FontFamily = "Forms9PatchDemo.Resources.Fonts.Pacifico.ttf"
};
entry.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve("Forms9Patch.CustomFontEffect"));

var label = new Forms9Patch.Label
{
    Text = "Custom Font Text",
    FontFamily = "Forms9PatchDemo.Resources.Fonts.Pacifico.ttf"
}
```

Full disclosure: I am the author of this package.